# Some bootstrap classes are not working (Bootstrap 4, Navbar and bg-)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on building a navbar and I've used the cdn for the bootstrap (css and js/popper). When using the classes, some work and some do not (d-inline, d-inline-block work while navbar-inverse and bg-inverse do not.) The menu is staying collapsed to the hamburger menu no matter the screen size or browser. I've tried just copying the sample code from bootstrap to see if I'm misspelling things, but that code has the same problems. I've tried adding the navbar-expand-lg class, but it doesn't change anything. I've also cleared my cache to no avail. I appreciate any help.

The sample code that I'm using is

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

however it doesn't work with this code either :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: blue;">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">[SITE LOGO]</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-dealers.php">Tire Dealers</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/why-used.php">Why Used?</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-knowledge.php">Tire Knowledge</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-products.php">Tire Products</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/contact-us.php">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
```

I'm using the following bootstrap cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My full code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>[SITE TITLE]</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
    form#search > div.d-inline-block {
        width: 23% !important; 
        margin: .5% !important;
    }

    form#search > div.d-inline-block > label, form#search > div.d-inline-block > select {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    h2.text-center {
        border-bottom: solid black;
    }

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Original Navbar that wasn't working: 
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: blue;">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">[SITE LOGO]</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-dealers.php">Tire Dealers</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/why-used.php">Why Used?</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-knowledge.php">Tire Knowledge</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-products.php">Tire Products</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/contact-us.php">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>  
        -->
<!-- Sample navbar that isn't working-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

        <div class="main-content">
            <h2 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Search For My Tires</h2>
            <form id="search">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                        <label for="width-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Width</label>
                    <select id="width-search" name="width-search" class="d-block">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label for="aspect-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Aspect</label>
                    <select id="aspect-search" name="aspect-search" class="d-block">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label for="rim-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Rim</label>
                    <select id="rim-search" name="rim-search" class="d-block">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label for="qty-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Quantity</label>
                    <select id="qty-search" name="qty-search" class="d-block">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ethacker,

I have a project using Bootsrap 4 nav so I copied your whole code and put it in my text editor to compare projects side by side. In Chrome the nav wasn't expanding and collapsing when resizing the browser for me so I put the classes I am using in the nav tag from my project into your code and it works!

Instead of:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
```

I put my classes in your code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
```

Maybe pop that in and go from there, may also consider moving the script down to the bottom just before the closing body tag.